# build with g++ fails: what does error: declaration of ‘.... throw ....’ has a different exception specifier ... mean

Tags: compiling, g++

I am trying to install a "toolbox" for a laser device 
(http://sicktoolbox.sourceforge.net/docs/sicktoolbox-quickstart.pdf)
and I am getting this message when I try to build it (command in section 5.2):

```
    Building Sick LMS mex...
    Building with 'g++'.
    /home/ark3420/SICK/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/matlab/../c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/SickLMSBufferMonitor.cc
    :131:48: error: declaration of ‘SickToolbox::SickLMSBufferMonitor::~SickLMSBufferMonitor() throw 
    (SickToolbox::SickThreadException)’ has a different exception specifier
    In file included from /home/ark3420/SICK/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/matlab/../c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/SickLMS.hh:
    24:0,from /home/ark3420/SICK/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/matlab/../c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/SickLMSBufferMonitor.cc:24:0,
    /home/ark3420/SICK/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/matlab/../c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/SickLMSBufferMonitor.hh:44:5: error: 
    from previous declaration ‘SickToolbox::SickLMSBufferMonitor::~SickLMSBufferMonitor() noexcept (true)’
    ./build_mex: Build failed!
```

Any clues as to what I could do to resolve this appreciated.
One issue is that this toolbox was written some years ago when Ubuntu 7 was current so i suppose that might be part of the problem!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are double declarations for a thow of SickToolbox::SickLMSBufferMonitor::~SickLMSBufferMonitor()
one in

```
/home/ark3420/SICK/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/matlab/../c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/SickLMS.hh - line 24
```

and another one in

```
/home/ark3420/SICK/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/matlab/../c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/SickLMSBufferMonitor.hh - line 44
```

open an editor to both files and check for the one that makes more sense.
You can try to uncomment one declaration and see if this works.
Or contact the author of the source.

Comment: thank you, I shall try that. The code was written around 2007 and would have worked with gcc/g++ 4.1 whereas I am now trying to compile with 4.7.  Is it possible that it was allowed in 4.1 but is no longer allowed in 4.7?

Comment: Let me please more about your environment where you try to compile this package. Double declarations are not allowed in c/c++ - no matter what version (for my understanding). But lets try if we can find the reason for this issue. I will try to compile this also if I know more about the environment you use.

Comment: That is very kind of you to offer. I am running LUBUNTU 16.04 and gcc 4.7.

Comment: I had to add #include <unistd.h> into SickBufferMonitor.hh & SickLIDAR.hh as mentioned in this blog [link](https://lms200.wordpress.com/2015/09/10/lms-200-driver-installation-sicktoolboxubuntu-and-first-visual-data-in-matlab/). Then the first steps `./configure`, `make` and `sudo make install` worked ok and I was able to run one of the compiled test programs. The next steps `cd matlab`, `./config_mex` also work ok. But then `./build_mex` is where I get this throw error.

Comment: Well, I managed it to compile this source but I have only a Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc 5.4
I had to modify the following files:
        modified:   c++/drivers/base/src/SickBufferMonitor.hh
        modified:   c++/drivers/base/src/SickLIDAR.hh
to add #include <unistd.h>

Comment: I remove the gcc 5.4 and installed 4.7. no other changes compared the previously. everything worked find. I will make a tar-archive from the compile sessions and the compiled source to provide you this. there  are logfiles (make*.log) inside sicktoolbox-1.0.1 where you should be able to see what was done. there are also a version information inside. just make a "grep '\-\-version' sick*log". inside the directory sicktoolbox-1.0.1 there are 2 log files from the make-session. make_2.log is the one with gcc 4.7. Hope this works for you. Download here:http://true-informatics.de/sicktoolbox.tar.bz2

Comment: Many thanks! I looked through the files but I can't see where you ran the `./conf_mex` and `./build_mex`? Thats where i got the throw error. These are in the matlab directory. You won't have matlab installed but you can probably make dummy directories for the two directories needed by `./config_mex`  eg `./config_mex /usr/local/matlab/bin /usr/local/matlab/toolbox`. Appreciate it if you could try that? Its the steps described in Section 5.2 of the pdf manual "Matlab Mex Interface"  :)

Comment: Just realized that you probably won't be able to try the next steps mentioned above as you won't have the Matlab mex stuff that is required in `./build_mex` eg  `$BIN_DIR/mex -g -v -output ./$BUILD_DIR/sicklms` :)

Comment: I've resolved this now - I engaged a C++ programmer via Upwork and he sorted this out in a matter of about 1 hour!

Comment: and you want to share this with the community now ?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the line:

```
    SickLMSBufferMonitor::~SickLMSBufferMonitor( ) { }
```

was replaced with

```
    SickLMSBufferMonitor::~SickLMSBufferMonitor( ) throw (SickToolbox::SickThreadException) { }
```

to resolve this problem.